# Scrapy Error when trying to connect to MongoDB TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'mongo_uri' and 'mongo_db'

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

This is using Scrapy CLI; I am currently running scrapy on an ubuntu 18 server, with mongodb and pymongo installed, but whenever I try to run my spider 'scrapy crawl event_spider' I get this runtime error: TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'mongo_uri' and 'mongo_db'

In my settings.py file I have defined:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'astro_events.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline': 300,
}

MONGODB_SERVER = "localhost"
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
MONGODB_DB = "astro_events"
MONGODB_COLLECTION = "events"
```

In my piplines.py I have:

```
import pymongo
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
import logging

from itemadapter import ItemAdapter

class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    collection_name = 'events'

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

        @classmethod
        def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
            ## pull in information from settings.py
            return cls(
                mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGODB_SERVER'),
                mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGODB_DB')
            )

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        ## initializing spider
        ## opening db connection
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        ## clean up when spider is closed
        self.client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        ## how to handle each post
        self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))
        logging.debug("Post added to MongoDB!")
        return item
```

What I'm wondering is if I'm getting this error because MongoDB isn't set up correctly on my server, or if its an error in my settings or pipeline file. I've verified that I have MongoDB actively running on 127.0.0.1 (localhost) on port 27017. I'm just kind of at a loss of where to go from here. Please let me know if I need to post more information. I tested my spider before implementing the database portion and it worked fine so I think I can rule that out.

EDIT:
Here is the exact errors its throwing:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2020-11-09 23:34:19 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 192, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 196, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jcmq6b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "/home/jcmq6b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/jcmq6b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 173, in create_instance
    instance = objcls(*args, **kwargs)
builtins.TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'mongo_uri' and 'mongo_db'
```

and

```
2020-11-09 23:34:19 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jcmq6b/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 173, in create_instance
    instance = objcls(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'mongo_uri' and 'mongo_db'
```

Comment: How did you init your object? It might sound silly, but did you pass the two-parameter that were required?

Comment: I'm new to this so I might be mistaken, but I thought that when the MongoDBPipeline is created it initializes itself using the information retrieved from the @classmethod from_crawler, which is supposed to go into the settings to grab my MongoDB settings I declared. I'm trying to follow along with this example https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

Comment: Your indentation appears that you declare the `from_crawler` method inside your __init__ , is that what's in your actual file?

Comment: Yes it was inside my init, I just  back tabbed it and it works now....wow thats a simple fix. Thank you!!! IDK how I didn't see that

Comment: Would you kindly accept my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just for other people stumble upon the same problem,

REMEMBER, when it comes to Python **IDENTATION** matters:

```
import pymongo
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
import logging

from itemadapter import ItemAdapter

class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    collection_name = 'events'

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db
    
'''
The problem was the following decorator and method declare 
inside the __init__ method (due to the wrong indentation in the orginal code)
That makes it a closure instead of a class method. 
And the decorator didn't run at all. Hence the error. 
'''
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
      return cls(
        mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGODB_SERVER'),
        mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGODB_DB')
      )

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        ## initializing spider
        ## opening db connection
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        ## clean up when spider is closed
        self.client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        ## how to handle each post
        self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))
        logging.debug("Post added to MongoDB!")
        return item
```